# htaccess redirect all traffic on specific domain to another domain, exclude folder and filetype

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Multiple alias domains pointing to the same cPanel account are sharing the same `.htaccess` file. I need a domain-specific rule that redirects all traffic from `aliasdomain.com` to `https://www.domain1.com` only if:

- `HTTP_HOST` is currently `aliasdomain.com` (with or without WWW and http/https)
- exclude folder `/medias/` - it must still be accessible from `aliasdomain.com`
- exclude all `*.jpg`, `*.jpeg`, `*.png` and `*.gif` files (even if the files are in root of `aliasdomain.com`)
- always redirect to `https://www.domain1.com` root, no wildcard redirect and no redirect to non-ssl http
- `domain1.com` needs to be excluded so if the same `.htaccess` file is on `domain1.com` it won't interfere.

I tried to adapt various code snippets found on StackOverflow but failed horribly getting it to work :( I asked a question there but mods told me to ask on ServerFault instead so here i am... Help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aliasdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^medias https://www.domain1.com/ [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* ensures that the rule is only processed when *not* requesting URLs that start `/medias`. (The `!` prefix negates the regex in Apache mod_rewrite.)

The first `RewriteCond` directive checks that the host being requested is `aliasdomain.com` only (with or without the `www` subdomain). (So, `domain1.com` is naturally excluded.)

The second `RewriteCond` directive excludes requests for image files.

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) if this is intended to be permanent and only once you are sure it's working OK (since 301s are cached hard by the browser).

Clear your browser cache before testing, as any previous/erroneous 301s are likely to have been cached. (Or test with browser tools open and cache disabled.)

> I asked a question there but mods told me to ask on serverfault instead

To be honest, this question is probably better suited to the [Pro Webmasters stack](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), rather than ServerFault! (Although this isn't necessarily off-topic on StatckOverflow, an example of the code you have tried is mandatory.)